# Copy and Delete File Leaves Zero Length File at Source

Tags: vb.net, system.io.file

I'm trying to copy a file from one directory to another. After the copy, I want to delete the original file. The expected result is that the source file no longer exists and the destination file does exist. The actual result is that the destination file exists and that an empty source file exists. Watching the directory during execution, the source file initially disappears then upon exiting the program it reappears with a length of zero.

Here's sample code:

```
Imports System.IO
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim sourceFileName As String = "c:\TestDir\source\TestFile.txt"
        Dim destFileName As String = "c:\TestDir\destination\TestFile.txt"
        System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFileName, destFileName)
        System.IO.File.Delete(sourceFileName)
    End Sub
End Module
```

If I were to remove the System.IO.Copy, the zero-length file does not appear. So it seems to have something to do with the combination of copying and deleting.

Are my expectations amiss? I realize I can delete the destination if it exists then Move the file, but I would like to understand why my sample does not work as I expect it. Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Can't duplicate.  I used the exact filenames and folders as in your code above.  Once the file was deleted, it did not come back.  I tried with a zero byte file as well as a file with some text in it.  There must be some other code that you are not showing that creates that file.  My VS version is VS 2017 4.7.02556.  I created a Console application using .Net Framework and not .Net Standard nor .Net Core.  Can you share the details of your environment and what type of project you created?

Comment: Is it possible some other process is holding/scanning this file?

Comment: No it is not possible. the extent of my code is as simple as I have above. All I did in preparation is create the directories and copy - using Windows Explorer - a text file into the source directory. Did you try what I posted and have success?

Comment: Thank you Chris Dunaway. That's interesting. If it worked for you, then yes there must be something about my environment. I originally thought it must be my code so I did what you did -- created a console application and manually created the directories and file. I expected it would work but it didn't! There is no additional code involved. And I am experiencing this on both my computers so I am baffled. One has VS 2017 15.5.7, the other does not. There is no other code involved than what I posted in my question. By any chance can you post your VS project? I'd be curious to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `FileSystem.DeleteFile` method from here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.deletefile?view=netframework-4.7.2

This should completely remove the file.

Comment: So you're suggesting that if I replace System.IO.File.Delete(sourceFileName) with Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.DeleteFile(sourceFileName) that it will work? Did you try this? Because I did and got the same undesirable result. Anyway, my question is why does my sample not work, not how should I do it. Sorry if that wasn't clear in my question.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure either. The Delete method should be removing that file. Question: Why not just use `System.IO.File.Move(sourceFileName)` instead of copying and deleting? That would be the proper way to do this anyway.

Comment: What you are suggesting is what I am already doing. My post here was to see whether someone has tried this and had discovered why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Has the `Read-Only` attribute been applied to your test file?  If so, you can try something like this:

```
File.Copy(sourceFileName, destFileName)
File.SetAttributes(sourceFileName, FileAttributes.Normal);
File.Delete(sourceFileName)
```

Is there a reason you're not just using `File.Move`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. As I mentioned in my question, I am aware I can use Move. I am trying to understand why the code I posted does not work.

Comment: Is the `Read-Only` attribute applied to your test file? As he asked?

Comment: I tried this with the `Read-Only` flag applied to the file to be moved and the program errors out with an UnauthorizedAccessException. Question: are you receiving any exceptions while doing this? Perhaps the file is in `Read-Only` mode, or perhaps the destination file already exists? Just some things to be sure to check.

Comment: hmiedema9: the file is not read-only. And the dest file does not exist already. Try this WITHOUT the read-only flag set and let me know if it worked.